# How to get filecreation timestamps as isodate

Tags: python-3.x

my script is checking for files in several directorys. If there is e.g. an mp3 I get the creation date via

```
time.ctime(os.path.getctime(audio_file_path))
```

What I need is an Isorepresentation of the date similar to

```
datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
```

my result at the moment looks like this:

```
Thu May 28 13:58:45 2020
```

but what I need is this:

```
2020-06-03T13:36:48.740664"
```

Is there an easy way to transform the timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.path.getctime returns a timestamp, so you can use:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(audio_file_path)).isoformat()
```